# Passing data to a confirmation page an getting a Undefined variable error

Tags: php

I am having an issue with this, I have a survey and on of the  question is a radio button group with an other selection that has a text to input the other.

```
       <h3>* What is the primary job position of the individual assigned to 
        this particular test?</h3>

        <input type="radio" name="job" value="Baker">Baker
        <input type="radio" name="job" value="IT">IT<br>

         <input type="radio" name="job" value="CEO">CEO
         <input type="radio" name="job" value="Flunkey">Flunkey<br>

         <input type="radio" name="job" value="other">Other 
          <input type="text" name="otherJob" >​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Once the user finishes the survey I display the user selection on a confirmation page. I get the following error: : Undefined variable: otherJob

```
         $job          =$_POST['job'];
         $otherjob     = $_POST['otherJob'];
         if ($job == 'other') 
         {
         $jobField = $otherJob;
         }
         else 
         {
         $jobField = $job;
          }
```

I pass the data to a submit page.

```
         <input type="hidden" name="job" value="<?php echo $job?>"> 
         <input type="hidden" name="other" value="<?php echo $otherjob?>">
```

Once passed to the submit page of course no data is written.

Comment: What about your form tags; using any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your variables has a "j" in lowercase, and the other one in uppercase.

- Variable names in PHP are case-sensitive.

`$otherjob` and `$otherJob` are treated differently and are not the same variable.

Just to be absolutely certain, you should also make sure that your code contains
`<form></form>` tags and using a POST method.

- It was not shown in your question at the time of your original post.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: He does have a form tag, and is already posting the form - Otherwise he would be getting an "undefined index" when trying to access $_POST content.

Comment: *True,* but I just wanted to make absolutely sure.

Comment: Yes it is contained between the form tags I left the out sorry